# SDL_Event and event types

Tags: c#, sdl

Not the best title, but, what is the relation between SDL_Event and all the SDL events, like SDL_QuitEvent, SDL_ActiveEvent etc...? I'm using an SDL binding for C#, and can't figure out what type to use for the type system when dealing with them; they are not subclasses of SDL_Event. Should I just use `object`, or is there some better way?

Comment: Are you using SDL directly or through some bindings?

Comment: Oh, actually, this question is obsolete since I'm not working on this anymore, but for anyone who needs this, yes, I'm using Tao.Sdl.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but just for long-tail searches:

an `SDL_Event` is just a big collection of structs (`SDL_QuitEvent` etc.). Depending on the `SDL_Event::type`, you set or look into different sub-structs and their data.

---

from SDL_events.h in **SDL1.2**:

```
typedef union SDL_Event {
    Uint8 type;
    SDL_ActiveEvent active;
    SDL_KeyboardEvent key;
    SDL_MouseMotionEvent motion;
    SDL_MouseButtonEvent button;
    .
    .
    .
    SDL_SysWMEvent syswm;
} SDL_Event;
```

---

from SDL_events.h in **SDL2**:

```
typedef union SDL_Event
{
    Uint32 type;                    /**< Event type, shared with all events */
    SDL_CommonEvent common;         /**< Common event data */
    SDL_WindowEvent window;         /**< Window event data */
    SDL_KeyboardEvent key;          /**< Keyboard event data */
    .
    .
    .
} SDL_Event;
```